# How can I save a number into a javascript cookie that can be printed on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, button, cookies, addition

I want to have a button which when you click on it adds 1 to a number, which is displayed on the screen. This is how far I got.

```
<button onclick="addOne();">Click Me</button>
<input type="text" id="inc" value="0"></input>

<script>
function addOne()
{
i++;
document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
}
</script>
```

How can I make it so that the number is saved into a cookie so whenever I come back the number is not changed back into 0?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The variable i has no starting value. You could do the following:

updated, see http://jsfiddle.net/sUHy2/4/

```
<button onclick="addOne();">Click Me</button>
<input type="text" id="inc" value="0"></input>

<button onclick="resetCookie()">Reset Cookie</button>
<script>
function resetCookie()
{
    document.cookie = 0;
    writeValue();
}

function addOne()
{
    document.cookie++;
    writeValue();
}

function writeValue()
{
    document.getElementById('inc').value = document.cookie;
}

window.onload = function(){ 
    if(!document.cookie)
    {
        document.cookie = 0;
    }
    writeValue();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I know sorry I missed that part, but how can I save the variabele in a cookie?

Comment: Added the document.cookie statement in the answer

Comment: But how will I save other cookies then?

Comment: and it doesnt seem to work, try it yoruself. It doesn't save the number in the input box.

Comment: look at this example, is this what you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/sUHy2/4/